# VSPerf "Instrumention" Tool has stopped working - VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling, visual-studio-2017

I had been trying out some of the Performance Profiler tools in VS 2017. All was working great except when I tried the Instrumentation profiling method. It asked to elevate the permissions of that process. Which I did.

Now every time I try to debug my app, I get an error that the VSPerf "Instrumention" Tool has stopped working.

I've tried everything, clearing out my .vs folder, bin folders, looking through the .csproj and .sln files. Completely repairing Visual Studio and removing whatever references I could find to "performance" in the options. It's getting really irritating.

Any suggestions?

[image: Error popup. Debugging does nothing.]

Comment: I got around the error message by renaming vsinstr.exe to vsinstr_old.exe. Found it in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools. Obviously, this isn't the answer but it gets me going again.

Comment: This works for me also. Did you ever find a better way of fixing this issue?

Comment: I did but now I can't remember how. It was something really stupid, I can tell you that much.

Comment: A link to the Microsoft Dev report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/148428/vsperf-instrumention-tool-has-stopped-working.html?childToView=151988#comment-151988